# Python Lock problems

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, locking

I am attempting to use Locks to handle thread access to shared resources in my multithreaded application, and things are not behaving as expected.  Please see the following code chunks (python)

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    updated = False
    print("attempting to acquire display mutex for update")
    if self._updateMutex.acquire(blocking=False):
        print("display mutex acquired for update")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("waking up")
        self.progressBar.config(style='Vertical.TProgressbar')
        print("attempting to release mutex for update")
        self._updateMutex.release()
        print("display mutex released")
    print("done...")

def shutdown(self):
    print("trying shutdown")
    self._updateMutex.acquire()
    print("mutex acquired...")
    self._updateMutex.release()
    print("shutdown done")
```

Here's the output...

```
attempting to acquire display mutex for update
display mutex acquired for update
trying shutdown
waking up
```

And no, this is not actually what I have running, but it illustrates the idea.  I've inserted a delay into the update method so that what I expect should be happening is this:

1. update method is called
2. update method obtains mutex and waits for the timer
3. shutdown method is called and requests the mutex, but it is presently owned by 'update', which is sleeping, so shutdown blocks and waits for the mutex to free up
4. update wakes up and finishes its functionality, eventually releasing the mutex
5. shutdown is notified that is may proceed and finishes up its functionality

I assume that the output should look like this:

```
...
attempting to acquire display mutex for update
display mutex acquired for update
trying shutdown
waking up
attempting to release mutex for update
display mutex released
#'done...' might appear on any line now
mutex acquired...
shutdown done
```

Clearly this is not what is happening, and I don't know why.  The problem appears to center around setting the style on (or otherwise interacting with) tkinter GUI objects. Things don't stall out until that call to set the style is made (You can see that the 'waking up' message is sent).

Aside from calling the constructor in __init__(), these are the only two references to the lock/mutex in the code.

Literally the ONLY thing that I am doing in 'shutdown' is to acquire and release the mutex at this point; if I do not do that, everything works fine: update continues chugging along and exits normally.  It's only when the mutex is obtained in 'shutdown' that things fail.  Any ideas what is going on?  What about my assumptions is wrong?

Comment: generally speaking, you can only call methods on tkinter objects in the thread in which they were created.